# My own kubernetes run does not produce the same results from the official documentations

Tags: kubernetes

I have been using Kubernetes lately, and I came across the loadbalancer topic. I have been following this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/

My problem is:

I followed exactly the same step starting with a yaml file as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: example
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The official documentation says the result is if I do **kubectl describe services example-service**:

```
Name:                   example-service
    Namespace:              default
    Labels:                 <none>
    Annotations:            <none>
    Selector:               app=example
    Type:                   LoadBalancer
    IP:                     10.67.252.103
    LoadBalancer Ingress:   192.0.2.89
    Port:                   <unnamed> 80/TCP
    NodePort:               <unnamed> 32445/TCP
    Endpoints:              10.64.0.4:80,10.64.1.5:80,10.64.2.4:80
    Session Affinity:       None
    Events:                 <none>
```

However, mine does not have "LoadBalancer Ingress" :

```
Name:                     example-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=example
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.1xx.1xx.1x
IPs:                      10.1xx.1xx.1x
Port:                     <unset>  8765/TCP
TargetPort:               9376/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30956/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I wonder why is that? Is IPs the same as LoadBalancer Ingress? Thank you very much

Comment: Somewhere on the page you mentioned, it says "1.4 release".  We're up to at least 1.18 or 1.19.  The answer might be in this detail.

Comment: Isn't 1.18 older than 1.4 and 1.4 is the latest?

Comment: I don't believe so. The minor version is a simple integer. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes#History), 1.4 was released in 2016, and we're up to 1.20 as of late 2020.

Comment: @LividFont where are you testing it? are you using something like Kind or Minikube? What is your Kubernetes version?

Comment: Kamol Hasan asked an important question.
@Livid Font Are you using kubeadm, minikube, Kubernetes on bare-metal or Managed Kubernetes Service ?

Comment: @KamolHasan I have 4 servers/ips. So I do ssh into those ips and installed kubernetes. I didn't use minikube.

Comment: @user15187356 Thank you for that. I learned something now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Kubernetes Service of type LoadBalancer in the cloud

You want to create a [Kubernetes Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) of type `LoadBalancer`.
As we can see in the [Kubernetes LoadBalancer documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer):

> On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the type field to LoadBalancer provisions a load balancer for your Service.

For example, when we use [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer) (GKE):

> When you create a Service of type LoadBalancer, a Google Cloud controller wakes up and configures a network load balancer.

This is an example from my GKE cluster:
**NOTE:** As you can see in the `Events` section,`LoadBalancer` was provided automatically by Google Cloud.

```
$ kubectl describe services example-service                                                                                                                                
Name:                     example-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Selector:                 app=example
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.0.1.66
IPs:                      <none>
LoadBalancer Ingress:     <MY_PUBLIC_IP>
Port:                     <unset>  8765/TCP
TargetPort:               9376/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31158/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  30m   service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   29m   service-controller  Ensured load balancer
```

#### Kubernetes Service of type LoadBalancer on Bare Metal

I conclude from your comment that you are not using any Managed Kubernetes Service ([EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc&eks-blogs.sort-by=item.additionalFields.createdDate&eks-blogs.sort-order=desc), [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), [AKS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/) etc.), but you are using Kubernetes on bare-metal.

In general, if you try to create Kubernetes services of type “LoadBalancer” in clusters that don’t run on a cloud provider, `LoadBalancers` will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely.

This is an example from my bare-metal cluster (the `example-service` `Service` is in the “pending” state for 23 minutes):

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
example-service   LoadBalancer   10.106.205.85   <pending>     8765:31091/TCP   23m
```

**NOTE:** As in your example, I also don't have a `LoadBalancer Ingress` entry:

```
$ kubectl describe svc example-service
Name:                     example-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Selector:                 app=example
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.106.205.85
Port:                     <unset>  8765/TCP
TargetPort:               9376/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31091/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Kubernetes on bare-metal needs a load balancer implementation such as [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) to provide this functionality.
**NOTE:** In general, `MetalLB` is not compatible with cloud providers:

> MetalLB is for bare-metal clusters, and even cloud providers that offer “dedicated servers” usually don’t support the network protocols that MetalLB requires.

---

I have created an example to illustrate how you can create a Kubernetes service of type `LoadBalancer` on a bare metal cluster with `MetalLB`.

First, I installed `MetalLB` by applying manifests as described in the [MetalLB installation documentation](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/).

Then, I created the `config` `ConfigMap` which gives `MetalLB` control over specific IP ranges (see the [Layer 2 Configuration MetalLB documentation](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/)):

```
$ cat config-cm.yml            
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.11.200-192.168.11.210



$ kubectl apply -f config-cm.yml                                                                          
configmap/config created
```

Finally, I created the `example-service` `LoadBalancer` Service and checked that it works as expected:

```
$ kubectl apply -f example-service.yml 
service/example-service created

$ kubectl get svc example-service     
NAME              TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
example-service   LoadBalancer   10.103.71.220   192.168.11.200   8765:32001/TCP   8s


$ kubectl describe svc example-service
Name:                     example-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=example
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.103.71.220
LoadBalancer Ingress:     192.168.11.200
Port:                     <unset>  8765/TCP
TargetPort:               9376/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32001/TCP
Endpoints:                <none>
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

As you can see the `example-service` Service has `LoadBalancer Ingress` entry with the address `192.168.11.200`.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes